# Remove all unused imports after moving type to new package?

Tags: java, eclipse

When refactoring a type to a new package I noticed that eclipse will add an import to the new package for all dependent types but will not remove unused imports that were a result of the refactor.

Note that the code base I'm working with imports packages rather rather than specific types which may be the reason why eclipse does not remove the unused import since it is a wild card:

```
import com.mycompany.packagA.*;
```

Is there a way to get eclipse to remove unused imports as a result of moving a type? If not, is there a more efficient way to remove all unused imports than doing so on a file by file basis?

Comment: I think the wildcards are the issue. When I move a type to a new package, Eclipse seems to do a good job of cleaning up explicit imports, both within the file that was moved and in files that import the moved type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the 'tree' of packages you want to clean up in the `Package Explorer`, then type 'Ctrl-Shift-O' to organize imports.  (or right-click -> Source -> Organize Imports)

Comment: Not a perfect solution since that will potentially result in unrelated changes but thanks for the tip. I think this is a good as it's going to get.